# Dynamic memory managment under Linux

Tags: linux, memory

I know that under Windows, there are API functions like global_alloc() and such, which allocate memory, and return a handle, then this handle can be locked and a pointer returned, then unlocked again. When unlocked, the system can move this piece of memory around when it runs low on space, optimising memory usage.

My question is that is there something similar under Linux, and if not, how does Linux optimize its memory usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those Windows functions come from a time when all programs were running in the same address space in real mode.  Linux, and modern versions of Windows, run programs in separate address spaces, so they can move them about in RAM by remapping what physical address a particular virtual address resolves to in the [page tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table).  No need to burden the programmer with such low level details.

Even on Windows, it's no longer necessary to use such functions except when interacting with a small number of old APIs.  I believe Raymond Chen's blog and book have some discussions of the topic if you are interested in more detail.  Eg here's [part 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/11/09/254441.aspx) of a series on the history of GlobalLock.

Comment: Right. Mac Systems 5-8 had a similar arrangement for the same reason. Now thankfully a thing of the past.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what Linux equivalent is but in ATT UNIX there are "scatter gather" memory management functions in the memory manager of the core OS. In a virtual memory operating environment there are no absolute addresses so applications don't have an equivalent function. The executable object loader (loads executable file into memory where it becomes a process) uses memory addressing from the memory manager that is all kept track of in virtual memory blocks maintained in its page table (which contains the physical memory addresses). Bottom line is your applications physical memory layout is likely in no way ever linear or accessible directly.